# Rails ajax submit fails to send params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**View File**

```
<%= form_for(@task, url: task_path, method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <li><button class="bton" name="status" value="Pending">Complete</button></li>
<% end %>
```

On clicking the Complete button the name and value is not received at the controller but things works fine if I remove *remote:true*

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery and/or AJAX? If there is some JS code associated with this then you should add it to the question.

Comment: What are the params that are generated in the log?

Comment: Just the controller and action

Comment: try to use f.button "Complete", :class => "bton", :value => "Pending"

Comment: Thanks, but can it be achieved thru plain html ?

Comment: @sureshvignesh Yes, but...Why?? By using the rails helper method, you get various advantages for "free" - such as language translations.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass **hidden field for sending those values**, If you need to send many values you can do this approach, without showing displaying the elements in Page

```
<%= form_for(@task, url: task_path, method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>       
      <input type="hidden" class="bton" name="status" value="Pending">  
          <li><button class="bton" name="status" value="Pending">Complete</button></li>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can submit form using form object:

```
<%= f.submit "Complete", class: "bton", name: "status"%>
```

If you want to use plain HTML tag then:

```
<button type="submit" class="bton" name="status" value="Pending">Complete</button>
```